# Is it possible to return more then one row in sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_A,
(select count(b.COLUMN_B) from SAME_TABLE_NAME b where COLUMN_B='X' GROUP by   COLUMN_A) as ALIAS_NAME
```

FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME c

Above query throw Error as

> single-row sub query returns more than one row.

but i need all the row it is returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_A,
(select count(b.COLUMN_B) from SAME_TABLE_NAME b 
 where COLUMN_B='X' 
 AND C.COLUMN_A=B.COLUMN_A   --- THIS WHERE CLAUSE IS ADDED TO MAP ALL YOUR COUNT RECORD WITH ITS RESPECTED COLUMN
 GROUP by B.COLUMN_A) as ALIAS_NAME 
FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    SELECT COLUMN_A, COUNT(COLUMN_B)  AS ALIAS_NAME 
      FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME 
      WHERE COLUMN_B='X' GROUP BY COLUMN_A
```

If that's not right, please post your real schema and an example of your data.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting multiple results in your column. your looking for something like this.

```
select  COLUMN_A, count(b.COLUMN_B) from SAME_TABLE_NAME b 
            where COLUMN_B='X' GROUP by COLUMN_A
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar subquery should return at most one row.  Hence, `GROUP BY` is *not* appropriate.  If you want to express this using a subquery, you want a correlated subquery *without `GROUP BY`*:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_A,
       (SELECT count(b.COLUMN_B) 
        FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME b 
        WHERE c.COLUMN_A = b.COLUMN_A AND
              b.COLUMN_B = 'X' 
       ) as ALIAS_NAME 
FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME c;
```

However, the better approach is to use window functions, available in the more recent versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_A,
       SUM(c.COLUMN_B = 'X') OVER (PARTITION BY c.COLUMN_A) as ALIAS_NAME 
FROM SAME_TABLE_NAME c;
```

Note that you should qualify *all* column references.  This is *especially* true with subqueries, where the scoping rules may sometimes not do what you intend.